# W3C Markup Validation Service

Tags: html

I use the W3C Markup Validation Service to check my web page and it works great. But is there a way to check the entire website? The site I am working on has over 50 pages. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool someone wrote for this purpose

http://www.standards-schmandards.com/2005/massvalidate/